# Ребят подскажите наилучший способ, как на PyQt5 сделать многооконное приложение?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Объясните начинающему программисту пожалуйста, как лучше всего реализовывать приложение, вот таким способом можно это делать, или есть более удобный и правильный? Этот способ я нашел в интернете

ui_Main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


import sys



class Ui_Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, Main):
        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.resize(800, 480)



        self.QtStack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()



        self.stack1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stack2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stack3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()



        self.Window1UI()
        self.Window2UI()
        self.Window3UI()



        self.QtStack.addWidget(self.stack1)
        self.QtStack.addWidget(self.stack2)
        self.QtStack.addWidget(self.stack3)



    def Window1UI(self):
        self.stack1.resize(800, 480)



        #PushButton1#
        self.PushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.stack1)
        self.PushButton1.setText("BUTTON 1")
        self.PushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 100, 100))



        #PushButton2#
        self.PushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.stack1)
        self.PushButton2.setText("BUTTON 2")
        self.PushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 150, 100, 100))



    def Window2UI(self):
        self.stack2.resize(800, 480)
        self.stack2.setStyleSheet("background: red")



    def Window3UI(self):
        self.stack3.resize(800, 480)
        self.stack3.setStyleSheet("background: blue")
```

Main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


import sys



from ui_Main import Ui_Main



class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_Main):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)



        self.PushButton1.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindow1)
        self.PushButton2.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindow2)



    def OpenWindow1(self):
        self.QtStack.setCurrentIndex(1)



    def OpenWindow2(self):
        self.QtStack.setCurrentIndex(2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    showMain = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Смотря, что вы хотите получить в конечном итоге. По большому счету, не бывает  какого-то одного "правильного решения", все зависит от задачи

Comment: например я хочу просто приложение в котором будет переход между окнами и там будут выполняться какие то действия в каждом окне и при этом я могу и возвращаться в другие окна обрат, простое приложение на телефоне

Comment: По вашему описанию стековая организация окон вполне подойдет. Есть еще `QStackedWidget` https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QStackedWidget.html

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а какую организацию окон используют в создание приложений на телефон?